# Image does not load in Android Apps

Tags: javascript, css, sass, jsx

I have an image that is passed inside a div and that works like a button that opens and closes a component.
I'm facing a bug where the image (arrow) **doesn't load in Android** apps.
It works 100% for the Web.
I need the image to be loaded in the Android Aplication and on the Web.
**faulty (Android App)**
[image: broked]

**flawless (web)**
[image: flawless (web)]

Jsx:

```
const [arrow, setArrow] = useState(isCollapsed);
  const [arrowStyle, setArrowStyle] = useState();

  const handleArrowClick = () => {
    openHistoryTable();
    setArrow(!isCollapsed);
  };


useEffect(() => {
      arrow ? setArrowStyle('expanded') : setArrowStyle('arrow');
    }, [arrow]);



<div
       onClick={() => handleArrowClick()}
       className={`${styles['arrow']} ${ styles[arrowStyle] }`}
  />
```

CSS:

```
arrow {
        position: absolute;
        width: 12px;
        height: 20px;
        background-image: url(../icons/gray-arrow.svg);
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        top: 27px;
        right: 40px;
        transition: all 0.2s ease;

        @include media-below($mobile-max) {
          right: 25px;
        }

        &:hover {
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        &.expanded {
          transform: rotateZ(270deg);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Make sure you are using https.

Comment: @Grumpy, But how can I pass an https if the image is local?